# Dynamically added linkbutton event is not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a comments section dynamically in code behind and having an issue with linkbuttons. 
The server side events I have wired to the link buttons are not firing. 
The buttons appear, but don't post back when they're clicked.
The buttons are not in an update panel.

I've added linkbuttons with events in other areas of the application with the same methods, and it's worked. I can't figure out what I'm overlooking.

I don't believe I'm having any issues with controls not rendering on postback.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
I call this from Page_Init ...

'THESE CLIENT SIDE EVENTS ARE WORKING
Dim lbReply As LinkButton = New LinkButton
lbReply.ID = "lbReply" + reader(0).ToString()
lbReply.Text = "Reply"
lbReply.CssClass = "lbreply"
textPanel.Controls.Add(lbReply)
AddHandler lbReply.Click, AddressOf Me.Reply

Dim scriptbuilder As String
scriptbuilder = "<script type=text/jscript>$(document).ready(function(){$('#"+lbReply...   
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), lbReply.ID.ToString()...
 .....

'THESE SERVER SIDE EVENTS AREN'T, THE CLICK DOESN'T POSTBACK 
Dim lbSave As LinkButton = New LinkButton
lbSave.ID = "lbSave" + reader(0).ToString()
lbSave.Text = "Save"
lbSave.CssClass = "lbSave"
lbSave.CommandArgument = reader(0).ToString()
textPanel.Controls.Add(lbSave)
AddHandler lbSave.Click, AddressOf Me.Save
```

The click event is defined like this:

```
Protected Sub Save(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

Comment: I thought I understood your problem, then realized the way you asked is a bit confusing. Can you post the actual subroutines instead of excerpts of your code all thrown together into one lump? What is IN your click event, and is that first code snippet all contained in the `Page_Init`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I banged my head against a wall for a couple days with this problem.

I moved the subroutines in question to a clean page and they worked great.

Starting from there, I  built up the page, making sure the subroutines still worked with each new addition.

I found that a required field validator that I use further up on the page was the problem. I can't pretend to know why. It only affects the controls added from code behind.

I'm going to handle the validation without the asp.net validator control and keep moving down the road.